# "Shoulder the sky " meaning

Tags: meaning, phrases

A.E. Housman wrote these words:

```
    The troubles of our proud and angry dust
    Are from eternity, and shall not fail.
    Bear them we can, and if we can we must.
    Shoulder the sky, my lad, and drink your ale.
```

I do wonder what the meaning is of the phrase "Shoulder the sky". In my mind, he is telling the boy to accept his responsibilities, but I have no real reason why I think so. Googling this phrase produced no real information.

So my question is, in the context of the poem fragment above, what does "Shoulder the sky" mean?

Comment: This will be a reference to the Titan Atlas in Greek mythology who was condemmed by Zeus to hold up the sky for ever. He is often shown carrying the heavens as a globe on his shoulders and, erroneously, as holding the world on his shoulders. Houseman is saying to the other person "do what you have to do and put up with the circumstances" which is slightly different from your interpretation, but close enough.

Comment: Google Books claims almost 35,000 written instances of [*shoulder the sky*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22shoulder+the+sky%22) (and twice as many for *shoulder the burden*). The anatomical metaphor itself is basic English, and the cultural reference (to the Atlas legend) should also be a trivial matter to look up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase '*Shoulder the sky*' refers to the greek legend of Atlas, who was condemned to hold up the sky when the Titans were defeated by Zeus and the other Olympian gods ([See here](http://www.greekmythology.com/Titans/Atlas/atlas.html) for a more in depth description of Atlas).

When the speaker says '*Shoulder the sky*' he is therefore telling the lad to grin and bear it, he is using shoulder as this definition describes:

> To bear or carry (a burden, responsibility, etc) as if on one's shoulders

([See full list of definitions for shoulder here](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shoulder))

It is a very similar phrase to '*Carry the weight of the world*'.